# Directly outputting pre-generated HTML with Happstack

Tags: happstack

I'm playing around with Haskell and Happstack and I'm trying to output string-based HTML directly without using formal Happstack functions. Specifically I'm trying to output SVG directly into the page (with `<svg> ... </svg>`) which comes from another module already fully generated as a string.

It's just a little toy program so I'm trying to avoid having to refactor the SVG generator module.

So my question is, in the following:

```
(f "<b> test </b>")
```

what is `f` such that test will appear in bold in my browser?

If that's not reasonably possible, what would be a more structured approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to use `toResponseBS`:

```
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L
svgToResponse svg = toResponseBS (C.pack "image/svg+xml") (L.pack $ "<svg>" ++ svg ++ "</svg>")
```

Another option is to make a `ToMessage` instance:

```
newtype SVG = SVG String
instance ToMessage SVG where
    toContentType _ = C.pack "image/svg+xml"
    toMessage (SVG svg) = L.pack $ "<svg>" ++ svg ++ "</svg>"
```

Now you can do `toResponse (SVG svg)` or even `ok $ SVG svg` but the latter will not compose well with non-SVG handlers via `msum` ...

---

*edit:* The above is relevant for serving an SVG file from a handler but you actually asked for embedding SVG in HTML which I first missed.

The answer depends on how you're generating your HTML.

If you're using `blaze-html` you want to use the `preEscapedToHtml` function:

```
preEscapedToHtml $ "<svg>" ++ svg ++ "</svg>"
```

If you're using HSP you want to use the `cdata` or `pcdata` function (I can never remember which, so try both):

```
<svg><% cdata svg %></svg>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yea I'm using Blaze. `preEscapedToHtml` is what I was looking for. From there I even managed to figure out the IO shenanigans around the random-number generation. o.O It's creepy editing a bunch of Haskell code and not getting any compiler errors. lmao. Anyway I'll probably need `toResponseBS` in the future, so thanks 2x.